# サーバー上に置いてある動画を再生したい

Tags: android, monaca, mp4

表題の通りですがiframeを使ってサーバー上の動画を再生したいのですが、iosでは問題ないのですがandroidでは再生出来ません。
何か良い方法はありますでしょうか？

```html
<iframe height="250" class="movie-iframe" src="http://○○.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: androidのブラウザ、もしくはWebViewの設定を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: コメント頂きまして有り難うございます。ブラウザはデフォルト(ブラウザ？)です。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: タグを見るにmonacaベースのアプリなんですよね。動画を埋め込むのに `<iframe>` タグが使われていますが、YouTubeの埋め込みタグとかではないんですよね？

Comment: monacaベースのアプリです。html部分にiframeで埋め込んでいます。実際にはjsonで動画urlを取得し、urlの個数分、動画が表示されるようにしております。最初はyoutubeから取得していましたが、こちらの都合上サーバーから取得するように変更しているところです。

Comment: `<iframe>` ではなく `<video>` タグを使ってはいかがでしょうか。もしうまくいかないようでしたら、Androidのバージョンと「再生できない」が具体的にどういう挙動になってしまうのかを教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

videoタグを使えば、再生可能だと思います。手持ちのNexus 7で検証しました。Monacaでしたら、Crosswalk版のハイパフォーマンス版WebViewを使った方が、WebViewのバグも消えるので良いです。

http://blog.asial.co.jp/1296

```
<body>
    <video src="sample.mp4"></video>
</body>
```